# Connect Content Type with Related Taxonomy Fields using Template

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms

I have a Content Type displaying correctly using a template, pulling out the fields to appropriate locations.

I now want to pull in related information from two separate taxonomies. I have a term reference to each Taxonomy setup as a field in the Content Type.

I have the taxonomy fields mapped out in the template, but the output is empty. I believe it is because I need to define a relationship somehow.

My current direction is to create out a view using EVA and render it to the template (which is poor for performance), but I am struggling to figure out how to define the relationship to the node.

Please provide examples of how you would approach this problem.

For context, Content Type is a job listing. Taxonomy B is information about the respective company. Taxonomy C is information about the respective city the job is in. Both Taxonomies can be made into Content Types if that helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating two new regions in my theme underneath Content, then I created a View with two blocks: one for taxonomy B and one for taxonomy C.

The view pulls in taxonomy fields using the relationship: `Content: Taxonomy terms on node`.

I have setup the URL pattern for my content type to be `contentTypeA/taxonomyB/taxonomyC`. By doing this, I was able to reference the correct term by using a Contextual Filter: `Content: Has taxonomy term ID`.

The Contextual Filter was a little tricky for me. As it was coming from the URL at a specific level of the path, I found that I could access taxonomyB through the `path component 2`, and taxonomyC through `path component 3`.

[image]

Under `WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS AVAILABLE OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED` I used `Specify validation criteria` as the respective taxonomy term.

[image]

Finally, using `Term name converted to Term ID` allowed it to see the plain english term name in the URL path.

[image]